# Place a 2D image on the top of the background

Tags: android, android-graphics

I am working on the android application with following requirements

1. Take images from gallery and display it as background.

This is done as follows:

```
btn_select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"SelectPicture"),PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    });

         }

    @Override


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(picturePath));

        cursor.close();

    }
```

2.Place a 2D iamge on the top of the background image.

3.Reposition the image by dragging 
4.Scale the image.

Anyone please suggest the ways to complete steps 2,3 and 4.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You may want to layer two `ImageView`s over each other, so use one of GroupView containers. Maybe `FrameLayout` would do (not sure about positioning within it). For example when defined in layout.xml, you create the group view, inside it define two ImageViews, and the latter one will be drawn over top of the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply